# What could cause my boost converter to output below its nominal voltage?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, boost

I'm very new to electronics and I'm building things and experimenting as a learning opportunity.  I've put together a boost converter circuit and it works OK, but I've noticed that under larger loads the voltage drops below the 5V I expect from the SMPS IC.

I'm using a [tps61232](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61232.pdf) and a [SRU1028-1R0Y](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/RU1028-1391535.pdf) per the TI Webench tool design.  I created a PCB based on the datasheet (image at the bottom) and a schematic based on the Webench tool.

Here's my schematic:
[image]

I have a cheap constant voltage power supply.  When the circuit is not under load, I can put 2.8V - 4.2V into the boost converter and get almost exactly 5V out.

I wanted to test current consumptions under load, so I used an Arduino (powered by USB) that drives a [cheapo chain of 50 WS2811 LEDs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AG923GI).  I added a potentiometer so that I can adjust the number of LEDs that are lit (with the intention of simulating different loads).

The output of the boost converter powers the LEDs.

I noticed that as I increased the number of LEDs that were on, the LEDs would dim and the supply current would stop increasing.  As I started investigating, I found that at various supply voltages, the output voltage dropped below the nominal 5V, and I'm struggling to figure out why.

Here are some data I'm beginning to put together:
[image]

The first thing I considered is that I don't know how to measure the output voltage under load.  I'm attaching my multimeter directly to the output pins of my boost converter and measuring it there.  Is that how you would measure the output of the boost converter?

The second thing I considered is that the resistance in my power supply lines was dropping the supply voltage below the minimum voltage of the boost converter (2.3V for this IC.)  That seemed plausible based on my measurements of the 2.8V supply voltage where the output voltage dropped to 4V once the voltage going into the converter fell below 2.3V; however, at 3.6V and 4.2V, the output voltage started to fall at 2.8V and 3.2V respectively which are above the minimum supply voltages.

The third thing I considered was that there's something going on with the inductor.  I wanted to try a few different inductors out (trying to settle on an adequate inductor that's not 10mm x 10mm).  I didn't solder the inductor to the board.  Instead I soldered some jumper wires to it and to the board and they meet in a breadboard.  That undoubtedly has some effect, but I'm not sure how I can tell.  Could that be causing my issues?

Further considerations of the inductor were that perhaps it was saturating.  That seems unlikely because the highest input current I've hit is 2.5A when I had all 50 LEDs lit with 1.3A at 3.8V on the output.  Is it possible I'm saturating this particular inductor and less than 1/4 of its rated current?

The fourth thing I considered is that perhaps I don't have enough capacitance?  I followed the Webench guidelines and added the recommended 3 output capacitors (at least similarly specified ones).

The fifth thing I considered relates to the minimum voltage.  Maybe the minimum voltage depends on current consumption?  I know that the efficiency drops off somewhat precipitously after 1A, but it's supposed to handle 2A . . . perhaps that's optimistic?  But, also, I assumed that when the efficiency started dropping, it would start drawing more current from the supply to meet its needs.  Perhaps, that's not the case?

Is it possible that IC can't generate enough current in the inductor?  Here's what I mean.  I think the current in the inductor is a function of the voltage in, the duty cycle, switching frequency, and the inductance.  The IC can only control the frequency and the duty cycle.  I was under the impression the frequency was fixed, but I suppose the IC could adjust the on time to meet current demands?  So, if the on time was double, it might potentially double the current in the inductor?

(Edit: after re-reading the data sheet further, it looks like the switch on time and the frequency are "quasi-constant."  Both duty cycle and frequency may change slightly and my current limits are being defined by those limits.)

So, an example could be if my LEDs require 5V at 1.3A to light 25 LEDs, that's 6.5W.  If the converter is at 80% efficiency then I need 8.125W on the supply side.  With an input voltage of 2.8V that's 2.9A.

It seems conceivable that the IC could try to increase the duty cycle, but I don't think doubling the amount of time would double the energy stored in the inductor so there must be an upper bound?  In my case it looks like it's around 2.3A of supply current based on my measurements.  Is it possible this is why I can't get 5V at 1.3A with a 2.8V supply voltage?

Based on this from the data sheet, it looks like this IC will generate 2A on the output side:
[image]

But, it's possible they have a higher input voltage?  If my previous example makes any sense at all, then maybe it would apply here too.  If they can generate 5V at 2A, that's 10W.  With 80% efficiency it would need to draw about 12.5W from the supply side.  If they can only supply about 2.3A, then perhaps their supply voltage was around 5.4V?  The IC will take 5.5V input.  If they have 90% efficiency, they could get it down to around 4.8V and only pull 2.3A from the supply.

One downside of this theory is that I thought duty cycle was based on the ratio of output voltage and input voltage.  That would imply that the duty cycle doesn't change as a function of load.

Option 6 of course is that I'm entirely off base and need to go back to the drawing board altogether.  I just included all of this detail because it seems worthwhile to describe where I've been in asking the question.

If you made it this far, thanks a lot for reading through this whole question.  Not only am I learning about electronics at a beginner level, but I'm also learning how to talk about it.

My PCB:
[image]

Comment: The first two things to look at is the input capacitor, try increasing it or add a bulk capacitor, as the datasheet says in 9.2.1.2.2.3. Second is the inductor, try one with higher saturation current, as the current peak in the pulses, the peak might be higher then the max saturation.

Comment: This is a 2-MHz converter, so all high-current loops are critically important. Is there any particular reason why you didn't follow the layout in manufacturer's example EXACTLY? And where are your ground vias on C3-C4-C5?

Comment: @Ale..chenski which part of it do you mean?  Some of the layout had to change to accommodate the larger inductor webench recommended. The ground vias aren’t there because someone on this site recommended that I exclude them. Some of it was that I was hoping to be able to experiment a little to try to understand the circuit and inductors better. What did I change that I shouldn’t have?  Would you mind explaining why being a 2MHz converter means that high current loops are critically important?  Is 2MHz high or low?

Comment: You wrote that you didn't solder inductor, instead jumper wires were used. In such high-frequency converters you should make all conductors as short as possible. Neither you should use jumper wires for the inductor. PCB layout is also critical, that why manufacturer always depict it in the datasheet. If you are just learning, it's not the best approach to start with designing such high-frequency power devices. If you really need such powerful DC-DC converter _working_ then buy the assembled and tested module. At least you should make it exactly as in datasheet.

Comment: @cyclone125 yeah. I intend to make it match the data sheet as exactly as possible after I decide which inductor I want to use. I used the jumper wires so that I could make the inductors interchangeable. I bought a few different inductors and I wanted to see if some worked differently than others.  Are you saying the jumpers might be causing my output voltage issues?  And/or that having the jumper wires might cause other (potentially hazardous) issues?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @D.Patrick Also, note that your peak current appears to be about a half-amp, which matches things if that was taken with the input voltage of \$V_\text{IN}=2.8\:\text{V}\$ and with a ramp-up period which looks about like \$\Delta t=180\:\text{ns}\$. \$ I_\text{PK}=\frac{V_\text{IN}=2.8\:\text{V}}{L=1\:\mu\text{H}}\cdot \left(\Delta t=180\:\text{ns}\right)\approx 500\:\text{mA}\$. This means there is about \$\frac12 L I_\text{PK}^2=125\:\text{nJ}\$ per pulse. Multiply that by 2 MHz and this is \$\frac14\:\text{W}\$.

Comment: @D.Patrick Yes, I think you should not combine high-frequency and high current schematics with jumper wires, and then expect them to handle, let say, 3-5 A. Also you shouldn't use LONG wires here. Particularly for inductor connection. Solder the inductor directly to PCB. I know that you want to do some experiments, but this can cause problems. It's not just "blinking LED" toy, there are many unusual and unexpected side effects. Also are you sure that C3-C5 top contacts are connected on your PCB together and then _where they should be_?

Comment: @jonk I don’t know that I understand the implication. Is that the portion of ripple current above the RMS current?  You’re saying that I’ve excluded that from my basic calculations?  Thanks!!

Comment: D.Patrick, From your picture it is unclear where your power ground is. The bottom slab does have vias to (I assume) bottom ground layer, C1 cap has them, but caps don't. Manufacturer has offered a nice 1-layer layout, without any vias in high-current switching loops. And yes, 2 MHz switcher is on fairly high side of this line of designs, so the construction of inductor also matters, the datasheet lists 3 inductors they tested/characterized successfully. Yet you elected to take an uncharted path with your choice, and breadboard style of component mounting is a no-no in switcher designs.

Comment: @D.Patrick I'm referring to your Icoil trace and I'm assuming the bottom is "zero amps" despite the alignment with the graticules. (The webers need to go to zero in each cycle.) Assuming that is true enough, I also calculate that your output voltage, when taking this picture was about \$4.37\:\text{V}\$ (below the desired output voltage, in other words.) Your LEDs will pull significantly less power if they are driven with that much under-voltage. So it's possible your inductor isn't matched to the need. (I didn't run TI's tool for you, though, and I don't know how you measured the current.)

Comment: @cyclone125 to be explicit, are any of those side effects dangerous?  For example, am I exposing a risk of potentially harmful electric shock or something?  Or are you saying that because of the wires I just won’t be able to get any useful data?  I did verify that all of the components are connected per the schematic. What do you mean “where they should be?”  Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @D.Patrick No, nothing dangerous to your health (at least until you provide dangerous voltage to the input). I mean, that you will not make it working as expected. Problems is that you will not get something useful (or power/voltage that you expected). You wrote that you excluded vias from PCB. Are C3-C8 on the top is connected to GND (common plane) on PCB? Or just with each other? On your PCB picture it's totally unclear where they are connected.

Comment: @Ale..chenski mmmm. I thought the ground pour on the back would help with thermal considerations. I also assumed there was an implied ground pour somewhere in the reference layout because I don’t see another way the IC would be connected to ground except through the vias. That’s almost certainly my own ignorance.  I did get the inductor recommended by the manufacturer; just not one from the data sheet. I also got others with various properties so that I could study the differences. It seemed a reasonable attempt to learn at the time. I’m not really sure how people learn without trying. Thanks!

Comment: @cyclone125 thank you!  They are connected to ground though my power ground and control ground may not be correctly isolated. Here’s where my PCB design was influenced: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/420946/69486. There is a rendering of the front and back. They are connected to a common plane. Thanks again.

Comment: D.P: there is indeed another ground in the reference layout, and vias to it, from the bottom of IC to improve thermal path, but the point is that all high-current switching spikes stay away from the other ground, and are completely confined within upper layer, and via inductance doesn't degrade switching speed. That's how they get low switcher losses and high efficiency, And you got just 55%. And learning doesn't come only by "trying", you need to digest the concept of switcher design, where the currents flow, and where the possible losses occur. Just changing placement won't yield much good.

Comment: @Ale..chenski what changes to my PCB would you recommend that I make then?  Get rid of the vias between the power ground pin and the input cap?  Anything else?  I’m trying to learn as much as I can. The read, try, ask for feedback cycle seems pretty valuable. The only downside is how often I get things like, “if you don’t understand x you shouldn’t even try.”  Or, “this is completely screwed; just buy something.”  I wish there was a resource for people like me who are just getting started. I may start trying reddit.  The feedback I get here is phenomenal but sometimes it’s very discouraging.

Comment: D.Patrick, you pick a pretty delicate and fancy area of power engineering to start learning. But read is not enough, the part of "understand" is missing there. Many IC datasheets provide better explanations on how the devices operate, and how important high-current loop are. The part you pick, unfortunately, has this info missing. Try read this IC datasheet, http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3478.pdf, it has better explanations. See diagrams in Section 8.

Comment: @Ale..chenski yeah. It’s hard to know what I don’t know sometimes. This is my 3rd PCB and everything keeps “just working.”  I’m trying to eat an elephant and I can’t figure out which bites to take first. People often say, “you need to understand this first.”  What confuses me about that is how you come to understand something without trying (and failing) a few times. I’m a software engineer; that’s pretty much the only way to understand something in our field. So, if “trying” isn’t the first step toward understanding, what is?  Not facetious; literally, what’s a good place to start?  Thanks!

Comment: I soldered the inductor to the board directly and got around 90% efficiency (plus or minus 5%) in all the cases where there's enough power to light the LEDs.  For example, I can't run all 50 LEDs on 3.2V because my power supply won't supply the amperage (and the IC goes into current protection mode and 50 LEDs at full brightness will be close to 2.5A).  It looks like there's a good chance that the jumpers caused the issue.  There may be other stuff wrong with my board, but when the data sheet says, "keep the inductor as close to the IC as possible," it's probably not kidding.

Comment: I have 3 more multimeters coming in the mail today. I will post better metrics later. :)

Comment: For ripple measurements, you need AC couple to 50 Ohm termination. for best results where possible or a 10:1 probe spring without gnd leads  . Try a PC PSU for 3.3V input to get enough current

Comment: Using Falstad you select part types with keyboard letters like r,l,c,w then draw, del or copy paste

Comment: @D.Patrick That what I was telling you from the very beginning. Don't use any jumpers for high-current and high frequency devices. Also don't use long conductors, keep them as short as possible. I mean that you should not use any wires at all, just smallest and compact PCB as manufacturer suggests. Particular attention to inductor connection. Then you will not have 90% of "mysterious" problems you may encounter with. What doesn't matter in "normal" electric design could matter a lot in high-current switching application. Every mOhm and mm matters. In general, this is very complex area.

Comment: @cyclone125 yes!  Thank you very much!  I definitely underestimated the impact it would have.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had soldered the inductor to the PCB with jumper wires so that I could test different inductors out trying to understand how different inductors would impact the performance of the boost converter.

@cyclone mentioned in a comment that the jumper wires were likely the cause of my issues and that was correct!

Once I started soldering the inductors to the board, every single one of them worked like a charm!  I tried 7 or 8 of them.

**Short answer: keep your inductor as close to the boost IC as possible.**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

## Updated

Your LED link indicates that [you have a **15W LED set**.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AG923GI) or **3A at 100% brightness.**  ( specs at end)
The WS2811 constant current output is **18.5mA max per LED** so 18.5x3 x50 =2775 mA and 50x IC may drain the balance (7.5% of 3A).
**Let's assume 50% brightness is 1.5A**.
 **The IC voltage tolerance is +/-10%.**

Your best power output within 10% voltage regulation is 0.588 A x 4.973 V = 2.9...W

The IC is designed for 2.1-A Output max or 10W and you have a 15W load.

Being a current mode boost regulator in continuous mode (CM), they may need to operate below 50% duty cycle to prevent sub-harmonic instability without special attention.  The L current rise slope must be > falling slope for this stability.

However since it rated for 2.1A and actual load is 3A at 100% or 50% duty cycle, it seems you underestimate your current load and L is too large to increase current if it is approaching 50% d.c. already. ( although our Vsw trace is negative logic < 50% d.c.)

## Conclusion

Spec assumptions were incorrect thus not matched to the supply capability.
A **CC 15W load = 1.67 Ω**  =R=V²/W= 25/15W.

## Suggestion

Test at smaller (5%) increments from 25% to 35% for max power.

**Consider instead TPS61230  5A regulator**  or alternate. with 20% current margin.

```
 Model: WS2811 LED pixel 
light source: F8RGB*1
IC Model: WS2811 IC
Quantity: 50 LEDs / set
LED Shape: Round
Color: full color, 24-bit
Gray level: 256
Length: 11.5ft (3.5m) per set 
Size: Please refer to the picture
The standard operating voltage: DC 5V
```

> Power: 0.3W/LED (15W/Set)

Comment: Hey, thanks.  That's valuable information!  What do you mean consider the TPS61230?  The TPS61232 is the 5V fixed output version of the TPS61230 I think.  They both have 2.1A maximum output current.  Also, by the way, I don't intend to drive all 50 LEDs with this circuit.  I want to drive maybe 10.  But, I wanted a way of testing different performance characteristics with different inductors and the addressable LEDs gave me a rudimentary variable load that I could build at home.

Comment: I recall reading the old WebBench 61230 was 5A , but could be wrong.  Same package, twice the cost probably both same inductor current limit of 5A. try the new WebBench wait 5 minutes and get more solutions at 3.5A. Consider the DCR and ESR of every part < 1mOhm for Ip^2*(ESR+DCR) and equation to keep duty cycle < 50%

Comment: now I see they just have Vfb divider for ADJ Vout. It may be hard to model phase at 2MHz in all the parts and traces but try http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-filt-lopass-l.html with all the R's Ron, DCR, ESR,L for input-output caps and Rs source and 1.5 Ohm load and enable Phase view

Comment: I made this in an attempt to see the phase response at every node with a MUX to out traces to understand ZVS effects on phase shift with every component. phase changes a lot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGZtG.png  Even I don't pretend to understand